# Nested Backbone Model is not fetching data

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

I have an Backbone/Rails application that lists servers and shows applications that have been deployed to specific servers.  It's backed by a Rails API.  I populate the servers from bootstrapped data in a rails erb file but when I try to load a particular server's deployed applications, the server is never called (confirmed by log messages).  I can get deployed apps back if I just visit the url so I'm pretty sure I've got something wrong in my Backbone app.

Here is my application start up:

```
window.WhatsDeployed =
Models: {}
Collections: {}
Views: {}
Routers: {}
initialize: (initialModels) -> 
    @start(initialModels)

start: (initialModels) ->
    @collection = new WhatsDeployed.Collections.Servers()
    @view = new WhatsDeployed.Views.ServersIndex({collection: @collection })
    @collection.reset(initialModels)
```

My View

```
class WhatsDeployed.Views.ServersIndex extends Backbone.View
el:"#serverDetails"

template: JST['servers/index']

initialize: ->
    @collection.bind("reset", this.render, this)

render: ->
    @selected = _.first(@collection.models)
    $(@el).html @template({collection: @collection, selected: @selected})
    this
```

My Servers Model

```
class WhatsDeployed.Models.Server extends Backbone.Model
deployed_apps: ->
    @_deployed_apps = new WhatsDeployed.Collections.DeployedApps({server: @})
    @_deployed_apps.fetch() 
    console.log(@_deployed_apps)
    @_deployed_apps
```

My DeployedApps Collection

```
class WhatsDeployed.Collections.DeployedApps extends Backbone.Collection
url: -> 
    '/servers/#{@server.id}/deployed_apps.json' 

model: WhatsDeployed.Models.DeployedApp

initialize: (options) ->
    @server = options.server
```

And finally my eco template

```
<h1>Servers</h1>
  <p>
    <select id="servers">
      <% for server in @collection.models: %>
        <option id="<%= server.id %>"><%= server.attributes["name"] %></option>
      <% end %>
    </select>
  </p>

  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Deployed Apps</th>
    </tr>
    <% for app in @selected.deployed_apps(): %>
       <tr>
          <td>Hi <%= app %></td>
       </tr>
    <% end %>
   </table>
```

The fetch call in the ServerModel doesn't fail and seems to work but the API is never called and the data for the collection doesn't seem right.

I'm new to Backbone so I've been struggling with this for a little while but there's probably something easy (I hope) that I'm missing.  Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: The indention would be incorrect if these are exact code.

Comment: Yeah, it didn't paste correctly but it's indented correctly locally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add a success callback to use the result of the fetch of @_deployed_apps like this:

```
class WhatsDeployed.Models.Server extends Backbone.Model
    deployed_apps: ->
        @_deployed_apps = new WhatsDeployed.Collections.DeployedApps({server: @})
        @_deployed_apps.fetch().success ()=>
            console.log(@_deployed_apps)
```